# No me aparece función SI.CONJUNTO

Tags: excel, formulas

Se supone que en Excel 2016 debería tener la función `SI.CONJUNTO`
que es como un switch en programación.

He intentado escribirla en inglés `SWITCH` o `CAMBIAR` pero no me aparece.

Comment: No tampoco...Si salen las funciones SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO o CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acuerdo a [SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Funci%C3%B3n-SI-CONJUNTO-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) esta es una función incluida en Excel 2016 pero sólo está disponible si se cuenta con una suscripción a Office 365.

Comment: Investigué en base a tu respuesta y finalmente encontré que es una formula agregada (y otras más) en una actualización del 2016 para Office 365. No así para Office 2016 y posterior.

Answer (score 0):

La solución viable si no te aparece la función `SI.CONJUNTO` es:

1. Cierra todas tus libros de excel.
2. Abre un nuevo libro de excel (o sea en blanco).
3. En esa misma hoja intenta usar la función. Normalmente, suele aparecer a simple vista cuando lo digitas.
4. Si te apareció la fórmula entonces abre tus hojas de excel en la que tenías el problema pero sin cerrar la hoja (vacía) que abriste.
5. Y ¡listo! Excel actualiza las fórmulas y te aparece en tus cálculos.